# How to go through a matrix alongside a vector?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to make a 2D lighting system for a video game. I have my sprites, in `32 px² (32x32) png` files. The colorkey is `(255, 0, 255)`. I use Pillow to load the image, and turn it into an array, and Pillow to reconstruct the image from the array.

Basically, I want to go through each pixel in the array in a certain manner, to brighten them (`((r,g,b)+(255,255,255))/4` for first layer, `x2` for second etc) I have a 2D unit vector that represents the direction the light is coming from.

the thing is, I don't know how to go through the array following this vector.

Example in M_3 :

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

> vector : (1, -1) (light source on top left)

should turn into :

```
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Your example can tempt a lazy reader into thinking this is about traversing the array along the diagonals.  I'd suggest a few more `vector` examples that aren't so trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)

a
#array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 5, 6],
#       [7, 8, 9]])
```

The elements are flattened from top left corner to bottom right corner, i.e the ascending order of (x_index + y_index), you can order the flattened elements from *a* by the sum of x index and y index:

```
idx, idy = map(np.arange, a.shape)
a.ravel()[(idx[:,None] + idy).ravel().argsort()]

# array([1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9])
```

---

To go through from a different corner, you can reverse *a* along x-axis, y-axis or both depending where you want to start:

For instance:

*Top Right (-1, -1)*:

```
a[:,::-1].ravel()[(idx[:,None] + idy).ravel().argsort()]
# array([3, 2, 6, 1, 5, 9, 4, 8, 7])
```

*Bottom Left (1, 1)*:

```
a[::-1,:].ravel()[(idx[:,None] + idy).ravel().argsort()]
# array([7, 8, 4, 9, 5, 1, 6, 2, 3])
```

*Bottom Right (-1, 1)*:

```
a[::-1,::-1].ravel()[(idx[:,None] + idy).ravel().argsort()]
# array([9, 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1])
```

Comment: okay, that works, but I don't understand how, or why, or how to implement it with, say a different vector.

Example :

with vector (-1, -1) that should return [3, 2, 6, 1, 5, 9, 4, 8, 7] etc

Comment: You can reverse the array before flattening it. Updated the answer with several other options.